# Example and intuition on natural couplings

Tags: probability, random-variables, optimal-transport, coupling

So I am following Barrera, Högele and Pardo's paper, about cutoff thermalization in the Wasserstein distance (you can find it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.10590)) and they prove the shift linearity property that goes:

> For $p\geq 1$, $u_1\in R^d$ a deterministic vector and $U_1$ a random vector in $R^d$ with $p^{th}$ finite moment, if follows that $\mathcal{W}_p(u_1+U_1,U_1)=\vert u_1 \vert$.

And then, the proof starts as:

> The sychronous replica $(U_1,U_1)$ with joint law $\Pi(du,du)$ (natural counpling) yields an upper bound for any $p>0$ as follows
> $$\mathcal{W}_p(u_1+U_1,U_1)\leq \left(\int_{R^d\times R^d} \vert u_1+u-u\vert ^{p} \Pi(du,du)\right)^{1/p}=\vert u_1 \vert.$$

Now, I have multiple questions on this. It is clear that it is an upper bound by defintion of $\mathcal{W}_p$ with an infimum. However

1. Why do they get the terms $\vert u_1 +u -u \vert$ inside the integral? Like, what I understand is that with the joint probability each event $x$ has the same chance to take certain value $u$ under $U_1(x)$, however not necessairly that would imply that the results are exactly the same overall. In that case, why would it be wrong to think
   $$\mathcal{W}_p(u_1+U_1, U_1)\leq\mathbb{E}[\vert u_1 + U_1 - U_1 \vert^p]^{1/p}=\mathbb{E}[\vert u_1 \vert^p]^{1/p}=\vert u_1 \vert.$$
2. The coupling has 2 entries $(x,y)\in R^d \times R^d$ so why does it look as if it were one in terms of the other? As if we had only $x\in R^d$ but two maps, one to $U_1(x)$ and other to $U_1(x)+u_1$.
3. Why does it seem as if the $u-u$ cancel everywhere to yield the $\vert u_1 \vert$ equality? This is related to the first question, I understand that if we take $U_1(x)$ and $U_1(x)+u_1$ we have some chance on getting a $u=U(x)$ and the same chance to get a $u=U(x)+u_1$. However, couplings take two entries and its all over $R^d\times R^d$ and what I said, maybe could work for the diagonal, but in principle $U_1(x)$ and $U_1(y)+u_1$ won't necessarily have the same chances and even less the same outcomes.

With that said, I think that I am not understanding correctly the intuition over couplings (or even maybe on the random variables), so any heuristics or explenations on how does this "natural coulpling" work, will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the fact that $(U_1, U_1+u_1)$ is a deterministic coupling (see Villani p.6 [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540710493)) since the function $T: R^d \to R^d$ given by $T(U_1)=U_1+u_1$ is measurable (i.e $T_{\#}du = dv$). Hence, the law of $\Pi(du,dv)$ is concentrated on the graph of $T$ leading to

$\int_{R^{d}\times R^{d}} \vert T(u) - u \vert \Pi(du,dv) =\int_{R^{d}\times R^{d}} \vert u_1 + u - u \vert \Pi(du,dv) = \vert u_1 \vert.$